# Hibernate Criteria API result narrowing on foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm using Hibernate Criteria API in my web project. Currently I got stuck in a serious problem. I've following scenario.

[image]

I want to get all students of a particular school (say with S_ID=1), but unable to do so. The problem is that I don't know what restriction to add to criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
 session.createCriteria(Student.class).createAlias("your_class_property", "class").createAlias("class.your_school_property", "school").add(Restrictions.eq("school.id", 1)).list()
```